# Are N95 and/or KN95 masks considered legally equivalent to FFP2 in Belgium and Italy?

Tags: covid-19, italy, belgium

In Mexico I can get KN95 and [N95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N95_respirator) masks, but [FFP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFP_standards#FFP2_mask) masks are only showing up as an import from the US and will probably arrive a day or two after I fly.

Are KN95 and N95 masks considered equivalent in Belgium and Italy?

I see references to FFP2 and to FFP2 Like masks, but I'm not finding anything that says they are legally interchangeable.

I'm assuming it's permissible to swap the masks mid-flight since we will be aloft for 13 hours and the masks aren't rated for that long, so I was planning to do the switch out about six hours into the flight.

This question is about the legality, being denied service or the right to board the flight.  I'm assuming once I get into Italy, getting FFP2 will be super simple, but I have to get there first.

Comment: On all flights I have been on since Covid started (6 total) taking off the mask for drinking or eating was allowed. While you probably shouldn't be snacking for the entire duration of the flight, it's certainly a good way to take a few "mask breaks".

Comment: Less worried about mask breaks that having a mask that is useful and effective.

Comment: Is your concern whether they will be considered "legally" equivalent as to fulfill local requirements in Belgium and Italy, or are you wondering if they are "actually"/"materially" equivalent for your own or other's protection or some other measure?

Comment: On the flights I've taken to Europe recently they recommend that you change masks after no more than 4 hours. And you take them off for eating/drinking.

Comment: Interest only:  KF94 are the Korean standard. They are very similar in spec to the other top quality masks - with a few practical advantages over some others. The answers relating to XN95 probably also largely apply to them. || I've found that an informal but useful test with a suspect mask is to see how well it removes smells in a high odour environment. The KF8=94 do this superbly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although the FFP2, N95 and KN95 standards are very similar, it is worth to notice that they are not equivalent.

As far as I understand the Italian legislation, it does require you to wear an FFP2 approved mask. The N95 and KN95 standards are not mentioned in the legislation, so strictly speaking, such masks will not fulfill the legal requirements. In reality, I doubt that anyone will actually verify which classification your mask has, as long as it looks like an FFP2 mask (and N95/KN95-masks do so). FFP2 masks are readily available in many shops, so if you do not want to stretch the rules more than necessary, I would at least advice you to buy FFP2 masks after getting there.

In Belgium, using an FFP2 mask is currently only recommended and not required, so using a N95/KN95 mask there will not be a problem.

Comment: AFAIK: while according to Italian law they are different non-equivalent standards, for the purpose of COVID regulations they **are** considered equivalent. I know that I heard and read about this in the news last year, so I'm confident with a bit of research you can find some documentation about this.

Comment: [3M explains the differences](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1791500O/comparison-ffp2-kn95-n95-filtering-facepiece-respirator-classes-tb.pdf). Although FFP2, N95, and KN95 are similar, they are certified using different criteria, and therefore not interchangeable in a strictly legal sense. Another factor to consider is that [60% of "KN95" masks on the market don't actually perform according to the standard that they claim](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prevent-getting-sick/types-of-masks.html).

Answer (score 3):

Anecdotal: I've travelled a lot to Europe during Covid including Germany, Belgium, Netherlands, Switzerland, Czech Republic, UK, etc. I've only used KN 95 masks since be bought a huge box early in the Pandemic and FFP2 were hard to get in the US.

I've never had a single problem or even just a question with that.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In practice no one cares, especially now in 2022 when masks are only a thing in a very small number of countries.

Comment: At the beginning of 2022 a friend was not allowed on a plane in Italy with KN95 mask. Switching to N95 solved the issue. So if it didn't happen to someone, does not mean it won't happen to anyone.

Comment: @dragi early 2022 was during the peak of the Omicron variant and was pretty much the last time anyone seriously cared about the virus. In summer 2022 the situation is radically different.

Answer (score 2):

KN95 is a Chinese standard that is a very little bit looser than the EU standard FFP2.

Comment: @mdewey The question was (in part) "Is KN95 equivalent to FFP2?".  How is an answer "no, KN95 is laxer" not an answer to the question?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica The question is about the use of masks in specific jurisdictions and as the other answer suggests not all of them have approved KN95 even if, as this answer correctly states, they are very, very similar in their properties.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Even if it is an attempt to answer, the statement is not correct. The KN95 standard is different from, but not necessarily looser than FFP2. Since the filtering capabilities are defined under different conditions, the standards can't be directly compared (in the sense of stricter/looser). The specifications are however so similar, that when it comes to preventing the spread of covid, they can for all practical purposes be considered close enough that the differences are irrelevant.

Comment: All this assumes any KN95 mask actually complies with the KN95 standard.  I doubt it, China doesn't care about quality of exports, so when you see a China only mark like China Export or KN95, it's junk.   (China Export is visually identical to the European CE mark. Clever.)

Comment: @Harper Apparently the China Export thing is a [hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking#%22China_Export%22). (Good point on the actual standard compliance though.)

Comment: In any event, due to blatant and widespread self-certification fraud, the CE mark actually stands for Chinese Excrement.

Comment: The main issue with KN95 is not the standard, it's that there's no certification unlike N95 or KF94.

Comment: Yes, the European authorities acknowledge there is a problem with some counterfeiting the mark, but it is only 3.6 roentgen - not great, not terrible.